# Must a CORBA application be implemented in the same language as the ORB?

Tags: corba, idl

I am aware that CORBA allows for multiple objects to be implemented in different programming languages and even run on different computing nodes. However, does this then require two different ORBs written in two different languages, as well?

Example: Node A runs Java application J1, while node B runs C++ application C1. Will I have to obtain a "Java ORB" for node A and a "C++ ORB" for node B, or can all/some ORBs interact with applications written in any language that there is an IDL mapping for?

I would be especially grateful if anyone could link me to a source stating this explicitly, as I would like to cite it. The closest I have found is ["the way a programmer manipulates a struct or union, makes a remote call using a proxy or implements an interface with a servant class is exactly the same across all C++ CORBA products, is exactly the same across all Java CORBA products, and so on"](http://www.ciaranmchale.com/corba-explained-simply/portability-of-corba-applications.html) . This makes me think that I would need two ORBs, but is not explicit enough. I would basically like to know if I can state that "As the ORB is written in C++, application programmers are also constrained to use C++".

Thanks

Comment: Let me try to clarify a bit more, with a specific example: "The ACE ORB (TAO) is a is a CORBA V3.0 compliant, C++ ORB" [link](http://www.theaceorb.com/) Does this mean I have to write my applications in C++, if using TAO?

Comment: Yes, that is what it does mean. However, it can communicate remotely with any other ORB in any other programming language via the standard protocol IIOP (among others).

Comment: Thank you all for your help! The consensus seems to be that an application needs* an ORB to supply an API in the language that the application is implemented in. Often an ORB will just supply an API in the programming language that it is itself implemented in, but there is nothing stopping it from linking its core libraries to APIs in other languages. 

*Also, there is the possibility of taking advantage of any language embedding features of the application language, e.g., calling C++ from Python or calling C from Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not important in which language ORB is implemented, it is important which language bindings it provides. For language L you need orb that provides bindings for language L. Often orbs just provide binding for the language in which themselves are written, but they can also provide bindings for some other languages.

Answer (score 3):

No. The point of CORBA is that it fully decouples the components.

Obviously, your applications need to use client libraries that they can interface with. Your ORB may only supply bindings for one language, in which case you need to find other bindings, or find a way to interoperate with them (e.g. if using Python, you could still work with C++ libraries if you wanted).

Try actually using the technology.

Comment: Er, but still a Java program has to have a "view" of the ORB, implemented in Java, right?

Comment: @DiegoSevilla: I don't know what you mean. Every programme needs to have appropriate corba client libraries to work with the corba system.

Comment: You and @DiegoSevilla seem not to agree. Does the comment I added to my original question change your answer, or are you saying that a "C++ ORB" can provide client libraries/APIs in Java as well?

Comment: @Vidar: I stand by my answer.

Comment: The ORB must offer bindings and APIs to the application implemented in the language that the application has chosen to use, but the underlying *libraries* (which are hidden from the application) can be written in anything at all. Typically it's easiest for the ORB vendors to match them up (say, by offering a Java API over a Java library) but they could implement the core in a different language. For example, a C++ ORB library could work fine beneath a Java API if the ORB vendor used JNI to bridge them. As far as the app is concerned, they're calling a Java API. Who cares how it's implemented?

Answer (score 0):

There are several approaches that can be used when implementing CORBA applications, but summing them up, yes, the ORB infrastructure has to be in the same language as your application implementation.

Both in Java and in C++, the IDL compiler generates *stubs* and *skeletons* that serve as a glue between the network and your program. You provide the implementation of your CORBA Objects, usually inheriting from a IDL compiler generated class (the skeleton). The skeleton gets the request from the client *in some way*, and then calls your implementation. The same happens in reverse in the client side.

Then, both the skeleton and the stub use the mechanisms provided by the ORB to remotely calling the servers and to answer responses back, even including stablishing network connections if client and servers are in different machines. This "magic" is implemented by the ORB, and has to be present in your program in form of a library, set of functions, etc. that the stub and skeleton will use to get the job done.

So, every program has to have some kind of representation of the ORB to interact with other CORBA clients and servers in other machines.

However, from a logical point of view, the ORB is seen as a layer, that actually and seamlessly connects both clients and servers, so, even when a C++ application has some ORB implementation written in C++, and a Java implementation have an ORB written in Java, by way of the magic of standard protocols (GIOP, IIOP), they can communicate with each other without problems.

Comment: I'll rephrase the key points to check my understanding: The client program sees the ORB as an API expressed in the same language as itself. And the ORB only provides such an API in the language that it is itself implemented in.

Comment: That is correct, so you need what is called "an ORB" (an implementation of the ORB API and functionality) in the same address space (and thus language) that your application.

Comment: Well, orb can be implemented in one language, and provide bindings for few more others.

Comment: Davorin: of course, there are plenty of examples out there :)